# How can I fix these errors from Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone

I am in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone, and have followed the MiniBrowser Tutorial located at the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526(v=vs.105).aspx

After following all the instructions, once I get to "Run Your App" portion of the instructions, under step 1, Build, the following errors are generated:

```
Error 1  The name "LocalizedStrings" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MiniBrowser".   c:\users\avery_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MiniBrowser\MiniBrowser\App.xaml   1   1   MiniBrowser

Error 2  The name "LocalizedStrings" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MiniBrowser".   c:\users\avery_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MiniBrowser\MiniBrowser\App.xaml   10  9   MiniBrowser

Error 3  The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.BuildAbortedException: Build was canceled. Failed to successfully launch or connect to a child MSBuild.exe process. Verify that the MSBuild.exe "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" launches successfully, and that it is loading the same microsoft.build.dll that the launching process loaded. If the location seems incorrect, try specifying the correct location in the BuildParameters object, or with the MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable.
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker blocker) c:\users\avery_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MiniBrowser\MiniBrowser\MiniBrowser.csproj MiniBrowser
```

What do these errors mean?

Comment: Do you have a LocalizedStrings.cs file included in your solution? It seems like it may have not been generated or perhaps you are using the Windows Phone 7 templates (which you shouldn't be if you followed the tutorial correctly)?

Comment: Thank you for that recommendation. I ended up going back to the beginning of the tutorial, and building after each step, until I could figure out where things went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone installed on my computer, it put the project folder onto the same hard drive as the application. For some reason, the solution in order to get this to compile, was to recreate the project on a different hard drive, and work from there.

Thanks everyone for your assistance!

Comment: Well, I've successfully set up my windows phone development environment !! Just in case anyone searches on this topic, I've created a blog post, 6 Steps to Windows Phone 8 Development. 

http://averysmith.pro/blog/6-steps-to-windows-phon​e-8-development

I hope this helps!